# How can I update the nick contained in all the favorite nodes when the user updates their nick

Tags: firebase, ionic2

I have a structure where a user stores their favorite users and in this node some fields like the nick, level and photo are repeated.

When a user modifies his nick I want to modify it in all the favorite nodes of the users that have this as favorite and where the nick is also.

[[Structure of nodes in database][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9BqQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9BqQ.png)

```js
{
"userProfile": {
  "8459xIX2aQhbRAVvLjCKYrkygG53" : {
    "email" : "4@4.es",
    "fotoPerfil" : "",
    "nick" : "nick4"
  },
  "ZQ65L8W54AW58FqNfXqknEW7O6T2" : {
    "Favoritos" : {
      "m43MatCb9bRQymSKYfWChaSpFPy2" : {
        "id_favorito" : "m43MatCb9bRQymSKYfWChaSpFPy2",
        "nick" : "nick22"
      }
    },
    "email" : "1@1.es",
    "fotoPerfil" : "",
    "nick" : "nick11"
  },
  "m43MatCb9bRQymSKYfWChaSpFPy2" : {
    "Favoritos" : {
      "ZQ65L8W54AW58FqNfXqknEW7O6T2" : {
        "id_favorito" : "ZQ65L8W54AW58FqNfXqknEW7O6T2",
        "nick" : "nick11"
      }
    },
    "email" : "2@2.es",
    "fotoPerfil" : "",
    "nick" : "nick23"
  },
  "toRFGF7CoKfb3UFcJYxOAXgeR9Z2" : {
    "email" : "3@3.es",
    "fotoPerfil" : "",
    "nick" : "nick3"
  }
 }
}
```

I have the following code but it is not enough to get to the nodes that interest me.

```js
  updateNick_Favoritos(nick) {
    debugger
    var updates = {};
    let ref = firebase.database().ref(`/userProfile/`);
    var query = ref.child('Favoritos').orderByChild('id_favorito').equalTo(this.currentUser.uid);
    query.once('value', function(snapshot) {
      debugger
      snapshot.forEach(favoritoSnapshot => {
        updates['userProfile/' + key_desconocida + '/Favoritos/' + favoritoSnapshot.key + '/nick'] = nick;
        console.log('key:'+favoritoSnapshot.key);
        console.log('key:'+favoritoSnapshot.val());
        return false;
      })
      ref.update(updates);
    });
  }
```

[[Codec][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkf4g.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkf4g.png)

What is the correct query to do what I want?
And since we are if they tell me how to get the value of the unknown route for the update I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You've also included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.